# Azure App Service outbound requests not routing through Vnet integrated NAT Gateway

Tags: azure, nat

I have a NAT gateway with a public IP that is associated with the same Vnet and subnet that I have my app service in as well. However, if I run a curl command from the kudu console, for example `curl ifconfig.io`, it still returns one of the outbound IP addresses of the app service and not the NAT gateway public IP that I was expecting.

Unless I misunderstand how NAT works I should see the value returned from ifconfig.io as the public IP of the NAT gateway, correct?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A natgateway with a public IP just ensures that all outbound traffic originates from that IP. It does not ensure that all your compute is happening on that 1 IP. So in your case, a "ifconfig.io" just checks the IP of the compute instance which is indeed the app service itself. But if you try to call an external web api from within the app service, that web api will see all the requests originating from your single public ip.

A simple way to test this is try fetching a storage blob with the storage account have logging enabled. In your log analytics, you will see the request originating from your public IP. This is a good way to ensure that your traffic comes from a static IP/s incase you have some kind of public IP whitelisting requirements.

Comment: This article matches my exact scenario in which the author of the article is able to return the NAT gateway's public IP. However, my configuration, which again is setup the same way, does not return the NAT gateway's IP https://www.sigmact.com/updated/zero-to-hero/part8-securing-webapp-2nd/

Comment: Have you tried the test I've mentioned above? If that is giving you your public IP then you have configured things correctly. But if not, then your setup is not correct to start with.

Comment: yes it showed in the storage account log as the NAT gateway IP and furthermore, it also started showing the NAT gateway IP in the kudu console as well. I'm not sure why it started working other than perhaps it takes awhile for the changes to take effect (I had let it sit over the weekend).